# Does ($\frac{p-1}{2})$! satisty $x^2$ = 1modp?

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

I'm trying to show that for p prime = 3 *mod4*, ($\frac{p-1}{2})!^2$ = 1 *modp*.

I assume I use Wilson's for the factorial and Euler's Totient Function for the (p-1), but I'm not sure how to string them together.

Comment: Do you mean $$\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!^2$$ or $$\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2\right)!$$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant ($\frac{p-1}{2})!^2$. Fixed in question.

Answer (score 1):

It is the case that, for prime $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$

$$
\frac{p-1}{2}!^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}
$$

To see why, first notice $k(p-k) \equiv -k^2 \equiv -(p-k)^2 \pmod{p}$. Begin with Wilson's Theorem

$$
(p-1)! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4\cdots (p-4)(p-3)(p-2)(p-1) \equiv -1 \pmod{p}
$$

Now rearrange this product in a clever way

$$
(p-1)! = 1 (p-1) 2 (p-2) 3 (p-3) 4 (p-4) \cdots \frac{p-1}{2} \frac{p+1}{2} \equiv -1 \pmod{p}
$$

Using our above fact, we obtain

$$
-1^2 \cdot -2^2 \cdot -3^2 \cdot -4^2 \cdots -(\frac{p-1}{2})^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}
$$

So we have

$$
(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} 1^2\cdot2^2\cdot3^2\cdot4^2\cdots(\frac{p-1}{2})^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}
$$

If $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, we have $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = -1$ so

$$
1^2\cdot2^2\cdot3^2\cdot4^2\cdots(\frac{p-1}{2})^2 = \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!^2  \equiv 1 \pmod{p}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response! If you don't mind, I'm having trouble following the step where we rewrote (p-1)! and turned that into $-1^2$ ⋅ $-2^2$ ⋅ ... ⋅ - ($\frac{p-1}{2})^2$ .

Comment: First rearrange the product $(p-1)!$ in the following way: $1(p-1)2(p-2)\cdots((p-1)/2)((p+1)/2)$. This is just a rearrangement of the terms in the product, and thus leaves the product the same. Now use the fact that $k(p-k) \equiv-k^2\pmod{p}$ for all $k$ to reduce the product mod $p$ as $-1^2\cdot-2^2\cdots-((p-1)/2)^2$